# What does " Victorian orphans" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, culture

Why did the man in following sentence refer his hair style as "Victorian orphans"? what does Victorian orphan look like? Is there any cultural gap I am missing, or is it a slang or something?

‘My hair. I’m only half done. I look like one of those Victorian orphans. "

Comment: If you google **Victorian orphans** you will find numerous sites on that subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Victorian orphans" refers to the [Victorian era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victorian_era), meaning later 19th century England. This era has many cultural associations, one of which is that the streets were littered with orphans or [street urchins](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/street_urchin).

I do not think they have a distinctive hairstyle, but they would have been stereotypically disheveled and unclean, and their hair would not have been professionally styled.

I would say this sort of image would be a typical example of what someone thinks of when they hear "Victorian orphan" (from [here](http://www.quailbellmagazine.com/the-real/satire-how-to-rid-yourself-of-a-victorian-street-urchin)):

[image: Three street urchins]

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about *British cultural history* rather than learning English as a language, but my first thought on reading it was that this somewhat crude stereotype only really survives through the portrayal of orphans in the works of Charles Dickens (the eponymously-titled *Oliver Twist*, Pip in *Great Expectations*, etc.).

So if OP's cited speaker had been a bit more on the ball, she might have been more likely to use the same term as the majority of her more "literate / literary" compatriots...

> *[Some dishevelled person looks...]
>
>    [...like a Victorian orphan](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like%20a%20Victorian%20orphan%22)* (About **81** results in Google Books)
>    *[...like a **Dickensian** orphan](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like%20a%20Dickensian%20orphan%22)* (About **109** results)

---

For a more "internationalist" cultural reference, there are the orphans Jean Valjean, Cosette, Javert, Marius, etc. in *Les Misérables (1862)* by **French** writer Victor Hugo. Personally, I'm not literate enough to know the adjectival derivative of "Hugo", but here's a well-known picture from the relevant Wikipedia page - titled [*Portrait of "Cosette" by Emile Bayard, from the original edition of Les Misérables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables)...

[image]